# Recommended pad size for desoldering?

Tags: pcb-design, soldering, through-hole, rework

I am designing a PCB that has will hold an Arduino Micro, as well as other components.  One of the electrical engineer mentors that are overseeing the board development has told me to increase the copper pad size/decrease the hole size for the pin headers in order to have an overall larger pad surface area.  He told me to do this because it lowers the risk of the pads coming off in the event that we have to desolder the Arduino from the PCB (dead board, etc.).

Currently, the holes and pads are circular, with the total edge-to-edge exposed copper diameter at 2mm, and the hole size diameter at 1mm (picture below).

We are planning on ordering our board from [OSH Park](https://www.oshpark.com) with their [2 Layer 2oz 0.8mm Service](http://docs.oshpark.com/services/two-layer-hhdc/) instead of the standard copper.

Is there a need to make the copper pads larger in the case of a desolder, or will keeping the pads their current size be fine after a desoldering?

**NOTE:** I cannot make the pin header hole much smaller, as they are square headers with a 0.65mm side length (corner to corner length is just under .92mm), but I can make the pads slightly larger if absolutely needed.

-Ben

**Pin header hole and pad with measurement:**
[image: Pin header hole and pad with measurement]

Comment: Ugh... are you really doing this instead of leaving the 80 cent microprocessor on the dead board?

Comment: The reason we want to know is because these boards will cost $55 for 3, and if the Arduino dies, we would like to be able to desolder it and replace it with another one while leaving all of the other components on the still-working PCB.

Comment: No reasonable amount of pad size will protect a board from bad desoldering.. (It might, but.. IMO thats the wrong mindset..)

Comment: Socketing the arduino is unpalatable?

Comment: It is unclear why sockets are not an option.

Comment: We are trying to keep the board low-profile, and we would like to solder directly on the board.  One of the three boards will have female headers, but that is for testing only.

Comment: Desoldering 28 through hole pins from a PCB is no small effort, and wrought with peril regardless no matter your pad landing ratio.

Comment: The main reason uC's fail is carelessness.  It is a learning process to avoid the soldering, ESD and I/O cable discharge pitfalls.  Don't make it so hard to maintain if you are this unsure and give more vertical room.

Comment: $55 for 3 boards comes to less than $20 per board. Desoldering and cleaning up will take at least an hour, plus repair time for the occasional damage. What are you paying your technicians (Including medical and retirement)? I can see reworking a bad resistor or capacitor, but I suggest you look closely at the economics of your approach.

Comment: I will talk to the mentors about using headers as a permanent solution.  One of the reasons we want to be able to desolder is because we have to order these boards in sets of 3, so if we need one board we have to spend $55 for another 3.

Is there still a recommended pad size for desoldering, in the event on of the smaller components on the board (2-3 pins) needs to be replaced?

Comment: Don't use large unbalanced copper ground planes or the 2oz copper will warp more with 1/2 the thickness of FR4

Comment: Bigger gaps for component leads inside holes will make desoldering easier.

Comment: Would using a non-PDIP package be an option? IMO, desoldering TQFP is a lot easier than a big PDIP.

Comment: I use hollow rivets sometimes, so the copper is hold hard to PCB even when I desolder/resolder it more times. For a small number of holes (as for one arduino) it could be done manually with primitive tools (like nail), just before anything else is soldered there. The hole must be larger for it, to fit in.

Comment: If the 28pin part is dead, take a pair of side cutters to it.  Clip each pin and remove the chip, then desolder each pin individually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fail to see in which way having narrower holes may help with desoldering. Less solder to remove? Well, maybe. But it will also make the removal of the part harder as you will have less room for waggling the Arduino pins to break any tiny residual joints in the hole. Thus, slightly wider holes could actually be more useful for the purpose of easy desoldering.

OTOH, bigger pads may help, but only if you use certain desoldering procedures. They can be helpful if you use solder wick, serving as a comfortable landing and working zone for it. In fact, if you're going to use solder wick, leaving some room around the Arduino Micro footprint for the desoldering operation helps too.

Of course, using a socket would be the best way to go. But if you can't due to design constraints, don't be afraid about having to desolder the Arduino. It's all down to using adequate desoldering techniques, it doesn't even require exotic expensive tools. Take a look at this [video](https://youtu.be/Z38WsZFmq8E) and see if for yourself.

Answer (score 1):

If the person performing the de-soldering is competent, it shouldn't make much difference. Honestly, if the boss says do it, do it. Alternatively, if these are protoboards you could suggest adding a socket designed to hold the arduino. These can be expensive depending on the package, but well worth the added expense if you'll be testing etc.